# Elegant way to test SSH availability

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I need a Python program I'm using to poll a remote server for SSH connectivity and notify when it is available. I am currently doing this using paramiko; attempt to connect, if failure, wait and retry until success or max retries. This works, but it's a bit clunky. Also paramiko seems to either connect or throw an error, so the only way I could see to do this was with a try/except block which is bad, bad, bad. Here is the method:

```
def check_ssh(self, ip, user, key_file, initial_wait=0, interval=0, retries=1):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    sleep(initial_wait)

    for x in range(retries):
        try:
            ssh.connect(ip, username=user, key_filename=key_file)
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            sleep(interval)
    return False
```

There must be a more elegant solution than this. Paramiko is my SSH library of choice but am open to any suggestions here.

To clarify, I want to avoid using try / except as a means to control the normal flow of code execution - it should be used for catching actual errors such as bad host key, invalid user etc.

Comment: `the only way I could see to do this was with a try/except block which is bad, bad, bad` why is it bad?

Comment: You're definitely right that catching `Exception` is bad. Catching the specific exception thrown by paramiko, however, is not bad at all.

Comment: Indeed, but using exception handling as a means of program flow is generally bad, as per: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Exceptions

Comment: I didn't bother putting the actual exceptions in because this was intended to be a temporary hack, and plus I'm lazy! The point of my question is that I don't want to use try/except to control the normal flow of my program - only to catch an actual error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by frb, a `try ... except` block is a good approach to test availability of a specific service. You shouldn't use a "catch-all" `except` block though, but limit it to the specific exceptions that occur if the service is unavailable.

According to documentation, [`paramiko.SSHClient.connect`](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) may throw different exceptions, depending on the problem that occured while connecting. If you want to catch all those, your `try ... except` block would look like this:

```
try:
    ssh.connect(ip, username=user, key_filename=key_file)
    return True
except (BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, 
        SSHException, socket.error) as e:
    print e
    sleep(interval)
```

If just a subset of these exceptions is relevant to your case, put only those into the tuple after `except`.

Comment: Fair point on my lax code specifying only a generic exception :p I do need a try / catch I guess for things like a bad host key as these are actual errors not "the server isn't up yet" - the point is I do not want the try / except block to control the wait loop (i.e. the normal flow of the code).

Comment: Can you include imports in your example script? It's unclear where most of these variables are coming from

Comment: @P.V. It's not a standalone example, just a suggested replacement for the `try` ... `except` block in the OP's code.